# mybatis cursor "A Cursor is already closed." error msg although transactional is defined

Tags: mybatis, spring-mybatis, mybatis-mapper

Mapper:

```
@SelectProvider(type = Provider.class, method = "retrieveTx")
        @Results(value = {
            @Result(property = "transactionId", column = "transaction_id", javaType = Integer.class, jdbcType = JdbcType.INTEGER),
        Cursor<TxModel> retrieveTx(String id);
```

DAO/Repository:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Cursor<TxModel> retrieveTx(String id) {
        return mapper.retrieveTx(id);
    }
```

Implementation:

```
private Result calTx() {
    Cursor txs = testDao.retrievetx(1);
}
```

I added @Transactional to the DAO, but I get err:

```
"A Cursor is already closed." at org.apache.ibatis.cursor.defaults.DefaultCursor.iterator(DefaultCursor.java:100) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6] DefaultCursor.java:100
```

I also add @Transactional to the operation, still not successful

```
@Transactional
private Result calTx() {
        Cursor txs = testDao.retrievetx(1);
    }
```

Comment: The rule is simple : the `Cursor` must be used inside a transaction. Adding `@Transactional` on a method that returns `Cursor` may not be right because the transaction is closed when the caller accesses the `Cursor`. Also, adding `@Transactional` on a private method usually does not work. If you have a service layer, try adding `@Transactional` to the service method called by the controller. See the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#transaction-declarative) for the details.

Comment: @ave get it to work, but since there is a bulk insert in the same function, the batch insert is stuck. the bulk insert is using SqlSessionTemplate(sqlSessionFactory(), ExecutorType.BATCH);